# The image file with the name "Cover" can have a different extension (jpg, png, gif)

Tags: php, file-extension

What's best way?

Search in the img directory for the file "Cover", but I don't know the extension.

Take the existing extension!

**is my solution clean? is there a better solution? What do you all mean?**

```html
img/cover.jpg
```

```php
$filename = 'cover';
$covex = glob('img/'.$filename.'*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$covexfrst = explode("/", $covex[0]);
unset($covexfrst[0]);
$imex = implode("/", $covexfrst);
echo '<img src="'$filename.'.'.$imex.'">';
```

Comment: Could you clarify following case. What if multiple ext are present on the folder ? What if no file are present ?

Comment: that's a good question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the `explode()` and `implode()` bits here..

```php
<?php
$filename = 'cover';
$covex = glob('img/'.$filename.'*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$covexfrst = basename($covex[0]); // get the first file name that matches, without the path
echo "<img src='$covexfrst'>";
```

Comment: the filename must be a variable